# How to .count nested_attribute boolean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean, nested-attributes, sidebar

The nested attribute of quantifieds are results. In the results partial a User will checkoff if their quantified result is a `:good` thing or not.

In the sidebar I want to `.count` how many good results the User has marked off to serve as a reference point of their success.

**SIDEBAR SECTION: layouts/_count.html.erb**

```html
<div class="stats">
  <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="following" class="stat">
      <%= @user.quantifieds.count %> #Works
    </strong>
    Quantified
  </a>
  &nbsp;
  <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="followers" class="stat">
      <%= @user.results.good.count %> #Remains zero regardless of number of checked :good boxes
    </strong>
    Good
  </a>
</div>
```

**quantifieds/_result_fields.html.erb**

```html
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :result_value, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Result' %>
    <br/>
  <%= f.date_select :date_value, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :with_css_classes => true, :class => "modular-date-field" %>
    <b><%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Result", f %></b>
  <div class="america3">
  <label> Good: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :good %>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**result.rb**

```html
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quantified
  default_scope { order('date_value DESC') }
 scope :good, -> { where(good: true) }
 scope :bad, -> { where(good: false) }
end
```

Should we add a method to the **application controller**?

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :load_todays_habits
  before_action :set_top_3_goals
  before_action :randomize_value
  before_action :set_stats
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  def set_top_3_goals
    @top_3_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.top_3 if current_user
  end

  def randomize_value
    @sidebarvaluations = current_user.valuations.randomize if current_user
  end

  def set_stats
    @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
    @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged if current_user
    @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance if current_user
  end

  private 

  def load_todays_habits
    @user_tags = current_user.habits.committed_for_today.tag_counts if current_user
    @all_tags  = Habit.committed_for_today.tag_counts if current_user
  end

  # Confirms a logged-in user.
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end
end
```

```html
class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quantified, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @quantifieds = Quantified.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
      @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
      @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build 
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
  end
end

  def update
    if @quantified.update(quantified_params)
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @quantified.destroy
    redirect_to quantifieds_url
  end

  private
    def set_quantified
      @quantified = Quantified.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to quantifieds_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @quantified.nil?
    end

    def quantified_params
      params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :metric, :result, :date, :comment, :private_submit, :tag_list, :good, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :good, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

**quantifieds/_form**

```html
<%= javascript_include_tag "quantified.js" %>

<%= simple_form_for(@quantified) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="america">
<form>
  
  <% Quantified::CATEGORIES.each do |c| %>&nbsp;
    <%= f.radio_button(:categories, c, :class => "date-format-switcher") %>&nbsp;
    <%= label(c, c) %>
  <% end %>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list, quantified: @quantified.tag_list.to_s.titleize, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Action' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :metric,  class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Metric' %>
      </div>

    <div id="results">
      <%= f.fields_for :results do |result| %>
      <%= render 'result_fields', :f => result %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    
    <div class="links">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<b><%= link_to_add_association 'Add Result', f, :results %></b>
    </div>

<div class="america2">
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to quantifieds_path, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to @quantified, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  <% end %>
</div>

  <label> Private: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :private_submit %>
  
</form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**quantifieds.rb**

```html
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  has_many :results #correct
 has_many :comments, as: :commentable
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true #correct
  scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'Averaged') }
  scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'Instance') }
 scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
 scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }
  validates :categories, :metric, presence: true
 acts_as_taggable

 CATEGORIES = ['Averaged', 'Instance']
end
```

**schema.rb**

```html
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150317171422) do

  create_table "activities", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "trackable_id"
    t.string   "trackable_type"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "owner_type"
    t.string   "key"
    t.text     "parameters"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "recipient_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "activities", ["owner_id", "owner_type"], name: "index_activities_on_owner_id_and_owner_type"
  add_index "activities", ["recipient_id", "recipient_type"], name: "index_activities_on_recipient_id_and_recipient_type"
  add_index "activities", ["trackable_id", "trackable_type"], name: "index_activities_on_trackable_id_and_trackable_type"

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["commentable_id", "commentable_type"], name: "index_comments_on_commentable_id_and_commentable_type"

  create_table "days", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "level_id"
    t.integer  "habit_id"
    t.boolean  "missed",     default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  create_table "goals", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "deadline"
    t.boolean  "accomplished"
    t.boolean  "private_submit"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "goals", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "goals", ["user_id"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id"

  create_table "habits", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "left"
    t.integer  "level"
    t.text     "committed"
    t.datetime "date_started"
    t.string   "trigger"
    t.string   "target"
    t.string   "reward"
    t.boolean  "private_submit"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "habits", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_habits_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "habits", ["user_id"], name: "index_habits_on_user_id"

  create_table "levels", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "habit_id"
    t.boolean  "passed",     default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  create_table "quantifieds", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "categories"
    t.string   "metric"
    t.boolean  "private_submit"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "quantifieds", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_quantifieds_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "quantifieds", ["user_id"], name: "index_quantifieds_on_user_id"

  create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "relationships", ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"

  create_table "results", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "result_value"
    t.date     "date_value"
    t.integer  "quantified_id"
    t.boolean  "good"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  create_table "taggings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "missed_days"
    t.text     "missed_levels"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

  create_table "valuations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "private_submit"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "valuations", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_valuations_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "valuations", ["user_id"], name: "index_valuations_on_user_id"

end
```

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :habits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :levels
  has_many :valuations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :quantifieds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :results, dependent: :destroy
```

**Thanks so much for your time!**

Comment: Could you add your *db/schema.rb*? It'll be easier to check what attributes there are defined for all your models. Cheers!

Comment: I think, the problem might be in your `QuantifiedController#quantified_params`. Could you try modify it, so it has following content `params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :metric, :private_submit, :tag_list, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :good, :_destroy])`? After that, can you try adding some `Quantified`s via web browser and test if correct values are saved?

Comment: Thanks @PawełDawczak! I added the schema. I added your code, which cleaned it up. Thanks. There was no positive or negative effect in the browser from the change.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce the problem locally by copying and pasting the code... Would you mind sharing the whole project, so I can set it up on my machine? This would be great experience, as changes applied would be send as pull request ;). This is my [github account](https://github.com/pdawczak)

Comment: I went thru a whole ordeal recently getting the app from github to bitbucket  :o Maybe we chat for a bit first before going down that path @PawełDawczak?

Comment: Ok, hope couple minutes is enough!

Comment: @PawełDawczak your answer is absolutely amazing! I never would have been able to figure that out on my own. From the bottom of my heart, thank you! All the best to you and your family. Don't ever hesitate to ask for a favor if I can ever be of assistance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your `Result` as follows:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  # rest of the code
  scope :good,       -> { where(good: true) }
  scope :good_count, -> { good.count }
end
```

Let's perform some tests in `rails console`:

```
u = User.create({ user_attributes })

u.results.create(good: true)
u.results.create(good: false)
u.results.create(good: true)

u.results.count
# => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "results" WHERE "results"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
# => 3

u.results.good_count
# => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "results" WHERE "results"."user_id" = ? AND "results"."good" = 't'  [["user_id", 1]]
# => 2
```

If you changed your `User` as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # rest of the code
  def good_results_count
    results.good_count
  end
end
```

which is much cleaner solution, you can use it in your application like:

```
# assuming we have data set like in previous step
u = User.last

u.good_results_count # you can use this line in your template
# => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "results" WHERE "results"."user_id" = ? AND "results"."good" = 't'  [["user_id", 1]]
# => 2
```

If, for some reason, the value remains 0 - as you mentioned - try performing the operations I described in console to see real data in database. Maybe this is not the problem with *fetching* proper data, maybe data is not saved correctly?

Let me know how it goes, so we're try to address the real problem!

Good luck!

**Update**

Problem in view is due to lack of proper association between `User` and `Result`. What currently is in `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # rest of the code
  has_many :quantifieds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :results, dependent: :destroy
  # rest of the code
end
```

When new `Result`s are created `through` `Quantified`s, this is what you have in `QuantifiedsController#create`:

```
class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
end
```

Well, everything looks perfectly all right, but the problem is actually in line `@quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)`. All `Result`s created this was have `user_id = nil`, only the `quantified_id` is set properly.

**How to fix this?**

By simplifying the associations! There is no need to store both `quantify_id` and `user_id` in `Result`.

If there is a relation like: `User` has many `Quantifies`, and `Quantify` has many `Results`, you can quite easily access `Result`s of `User`s by proper declaration in `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # rest of the code
  has_many :quantifieds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :results, through: :quantifieds
  # rest of the code
end
```

This is quite clever thing! Let's see, what happens under the hood:

```
u = User.last
u.results
Result Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "results".* FROM "results" INNER JOIN "quantifieds" ON "results"."quantified_id" = "quantifieds"."id" WHERE "quantifieds"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY date_value DESC  [["user_id", 5]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy ...>
```

Now, when relation is set up as described above, the proper counts should appear in website.

There is no need to store `user_id` in `Result`, so you can freely remove it!

Comment: Thanks Pawel for your insightful answer! If your around let's chat. I'll send you a request now. I used your code but it doesn't seem to work, but that might be my fault :)

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com - Unfortunately, I don't have much time at the moment (tiny baby crying) - but we can try ~5 min to catch up!

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com - My apologies, but I need to finish for today... Do you have the code somewhere in github maybe? Please add me - [pdawczak](https://github.com/pdawczak), so I can try investigating the problem. Or, if  you don't like giving the access (which I understand completely!), could you add code of your controller and *whole* template for view processing the form with partial of **quantifieds/_result_fields.html.erb**? I think this is the problem with persisting data, rather than reading! Hope to catch up shortly!

Comment: That's adorable but then again I don't have to listen to him/her. I added the code above. No worries Pawel.

Comment: Part of my confusion with your answer is I'm not use to using rails c. I ran your first line but I get an error: `2.1.3 :009 > u = User.create({ user_attributes })
SyntaxError: (irb):9: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
u = User.create({ user_attributes })`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com - Well, I made a shortcut - I don't know what attributes has your `User`, but you should replace it with *minimal* amount of attributes that allow to create a `User` (if you have any validations). If your `User` as a mandatory attribute of eg. `email`, replace this line with `u = User.create({ email: "sample@email.com" })`. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: Got it with the next line we get this: `2.1.3 :025 > u.results.create(good: true)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: You cannot call create unless the parent is saved` aka Quantifieds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73369/discussion-between-pawel-dawczak-and-anthonygalli-com).

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="stats">
  <a href="<%= following_user_path(@jadenmcgruder) %>">
    <strong id="following" class="stat">
      <%= @jadenmcgruder.quantifieds.count %> #Works
    </strong>
    Quantified
  </a>
  &nbsp;
  <a href="<%= followers_user _path(@jadenmcgruder) %>">
    <strong id="followers" class="stat">
      <%= @jadenmcgruder.results.good.count %> #Remains zero regardless of number of checked :good boxes
    </strong>
    Good
  </a>
</div>
```